# Can't apply concat function in WSO2 ESB CONFIGURATION with json-eval

Tags: xml, concatenation, jsonpath, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I'm trying to set this expression in order to obtain the output file name as a concat between the name of the city and the extention of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="WriteFile_City" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<property expression="concat(json-eval($.city.name),'.xml')"
    name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" scope="transport"
    type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
<property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
<send>
    <endpoint>
        <address uri="vfs:file:///C:/myFolder"/>
    </endpoint>
</send>
</sequence>
```

If I only try to insert the name of the city, it works: the third line would be

```
<property expression="json-eval($.city.name)"
```

and in this way i save my output in a file named "London", for example. But i need to save output as "London.xml", but i can't understand where is the problem with this concat function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you tried fn:concat(json-eval($.city.name),'.xml') instead of simply concat(....) ?
I know that I already add issue when using functions with some expression. I generally also try to first declare a property and then use it like

```
<property expression="json-eval($.city.name)" name="city"/>
<property expression="concat(get-property('city'),'.xml')"
name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" scope="transport"
type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
```

Comment: I already tried fn:concat(json-eval($.city.name),'.xml') but didn't work. Your solution with "city" property works fine, i can't understand why we are forced to use it but it's great... thanks a lot.

Comment: maybe a bug, you're right I don't know why it's not working. I don't know how to get an access to wso2 jira to submit a defect. I've also [another question that I would like to raise to them regarding dss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588602/wso2-dss-issue-when-selecting-timestamps-from-database)

Answer (score 3):

You can use as below,

```
<property expression="json-eval($.city.name)" name="city"/>
<property expression="fn:concat($ctx:city, '.xml')" name="name-of-attribute" type="STRING" scope="default"/>
```

If you want to concat many parameters use as below,

```
<property expression="fn:concat($ctx:city ,'.', 'xml')" name="name-of-attribute" type="STRING" scope="default"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

there, the right way is:

```
    <property expression="fn:concat(get-property('city'),'.xml')" name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" scope="transport" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
```